# Не получается работать с приватным атрибутом в Python

Tags: python, anaconda

подскажите, пожалуйста, почему при работе с приватным атрибутом может выходить ошибка? Изучаю python, смотрю приватные атрибуты сейчас)
В классе создаю атрибут с __ , пытаюсь к нему обратиться, вижу ошибку в Anaconda.

```
class Object():

    MAX_SPEED = 100
    
    def __init__(self, var):        
        self.__var = var
        
c = Object('Test')
c._Object.__var
```

[image: скриншот ошибки]

Comment: приватные атрибуты (на  то они и приватные) доступны только внутри класса. ну а так - `c._Object__var` - точку уберите

Comment: @splash58 спасибо!